# Azure-Pipelines Dynamically Input

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

Im building the pipeline in azure devops from the YAML where i'm taking the input dynamically from the user but i have not to **restrict** the user to enter the input. Its optional basically but the problem is i'm not able to remove the required keywork's. If anyone have the idea how to disable it Please guide me.

Till now i have checked the branch polices

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOkv2.png)

Comment: What does your YAML look like? What is the scenario you're trying to implement? Be specific.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad, no way seems could restrict users from edit the input runtime parameter, but maybe you could try to use variable? Variables could be set as read only, please kindly see whether the doc could help to achieve your goal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-variable-properties. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad, have you already tried the following method? Does it meet your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, you need to remove the **required** keyword of the parameters input.

For example:

[image]

By default, the value of parameters must exist when running the pipeline, so it will display the required mark.

> Its optional basically but the problem is i'm not able to remove the required keywork's

To meet your requirement, you can define the default value as empty(`' '`) in YAML pipeline.

For example:

```
parameters:
  - name: test
    displayName: Please Provide the Resource Group Name
    type: string
    default: ' '
```

**Result:** it will remove the required mark.

[image]